# using a java construct parameter in one class inside another class

Tags: java

I have this construct in .Author

```
package author;

public class Author {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private char gender;

    public Author (String name, String email, char gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
    public char gender () {
        return gender;
    }
    public String getEmail () {
        return email;
    }
    public void SetEmail (String userEmail) {
        email = userEmail; 
    }
    public String toString () {
        return "Author info: " + " [name: " +name + ", " + " gender: " + gender +", " + " email " + email + "]";
    }

}
```

I have another class named .Book, I want to use the "name" variable from the Author construct inside another construct inside the .Book as shown below:

```
public class Book {
    private String bookName;
    private String author;
    private double price;
    private int qty;

    public Book (String bookName, Author name, double price) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        // here I'm getting an error saying ";" required
        this.author = Author name;
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

I'm getting an error (shown in the second code) so clearly I'm not doing it right and don't know how. Any help?

Comment: Can you show the entire file as one??

Comment: I added the full .author

Comment: i posted the answer. Pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Book {
    private String bookName;
    private Author author; //it should be Author, not String
    private double price;
    private int qty;

    public Book (String bookName, Author name, double price) {
        this.bookName = bookName;
        this.author = name; //here was ur mistake
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Try this code. Assumed, while constructing the book, you do like

```
Book book = new Book("name", new Author("name", "name@mail", m), 22.0);
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying "Author cannot be converted to string"

Comment: thanks it is correct! I got a -1 on my question. if you think otherwise, please vote it up

Comment: Ok @zamzam . I do think other wise.